# Row function to join together binary number elements

Tags: list-manipulation, binary, row

I am trying to join entries of binary numbers at the lowest level of a nested list, e.g.

```
testlist = {{{100, 100}, {101, 101}}, {{110, 110}, {111, 111}}, {{111,
     100}, {111, 110}}, {{101, 111}, {110, 101}}}
```

Using the Row function seems to work

```
rowlist = Table[Row[testlist[[i, j]]], {i, 4}, {j, 2}]
```

with the resulting output displayed as

```
{{100100,101101},{110110,111111},{111100,111110},{101111,110101}
```

which is the desired result. However when I check the first entry at the third level, i.e.  `rowlist[[1,1,1]]` I get `{100, 100}`
which suggests that this is merely a change of display rather than fundamentally changing the list, as does the output from `rowlist` when pasted here

```
{{Row[{100, 100}], Row[{101, 101}]}, {Row[{110, 110}], 
  Row[{111, 111}]}, {Row[{111, 100}], 
  Row[{111, 110}]}, {Row[{101, 111}], Row[{110, 101}]}}
```

How can I change the list so that the first entry at the deepest level is `rowlist[[1,1]]=100100` ?

Comment: `Map[{10^Floor[Log10[#[[2]]] + 1], 1} . # &, testlist, {2}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
testlist = {{{100, 100}, {101, 101}}, {{110, 110}, {111, 111}}, {{111,
     100}, {111, 110}}, {{101, 111}, {110, 101}}}

Map[StringJoin,
 Map[ToString, testlist, {-1}]  
 , {-2}
 ]
```

> ```
> {{"100100", "101101"}, {"110110", "111111"}, {"111100", 
>   "111110"}, {"101111", "110101"}}
> ```

---

The inner `Map` applies to the leaves and converts the entries using `ToString`. Depending on the entries, some zero padding may be required in the general case.

The outer `Map` applies one level up and joins the strings produced in the first step using `StringJoin`.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to convert these strings (at leaf level now) to a decimal number, then add another `Map`. A string can be passed to `FromDigits` directly and uses base 10 as default.

```
Map[FromDigits,
 Map[StringJoin,
  Map[ToString, testlist, {-1}
   ]
  , {-2}
  ]
 , {-1}
 ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's define a function that joins together two of the entries:

```
join[{x_, y_}] := ToExpression[StringJoin[{ToString[x], ToString[y]}]];
```

Now we can use this function to answer your question. With testlist as you have defined it above, you can get your desired form by:

```
Partition[join /@ Flatten[testlist, 1], 2]
{{100100, 101101}, {110110, 111111}, {111100, 111110}, {101111, 110101}}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Map[FromDigits @* Flatten @* IntegerDigits, testlist, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{100100, 101101}, {110110, 111111}, {111100, 111110}, {101111, 110101}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

### 1

`{100, 100} -> 100100`

```
f[{x_,y_}] = x*10^IntegerLength[x] + y;
f[{100,100}];
```

### 2

```
g = Map[f]
g[{{100, 100}, {101, 101}}]
```

get `{100100,101101}`

### 3

```
 {{{100, 100}, {101, 101}}, {{110, 110}, {111, 111}}, {{111,
     100}, {111, 110}}, {{101, 111}, {110, 101}}} // Map[g]
```

> ```
> {{100100, 101101}, {110110, 111111}, {111100, 111110}, {101111, 110101}}
> ```

just step by step.

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{{100, 100}, {101, 101}}, {{110, 110}, {111, 111}},
   {{111, 100}, {111, 110}}, {{101, 111}, {110, 101}}};
```

Using `Replace` at level 2

```
Replace[list, {a_, b_} :> ToExpression[ToString[a] <> ToString[b]], {2}]
```

{{100100, 101101}, {110110, 111111}, {111100, 111110}, {101111,
110101}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{{100, 100}, {101, 101}}, {{110, 110}, {111, 111}},
   {{111, 100}, {111, 110}}, {{101, 111}, {110, 101}}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. v_?VectorQ :> ToExpression["" <> ToString /@ v]
```

*Result*:

> `{{100100, 101101}, {110110, 111111}, {111100, 111110}, {101111, 110101}}`

Or using `ReplaceAll`, `IntegerDigits` and `FromDigits`:

```
list /. v_?VectorQ :> FromDigits@*Join @@ IntegerDigits[v]
```

*Result*:

> `{{100100, 101101}, {110110, 111111}, {111100, 111110}, {101111, 110101}}`